# Google backend GCS Bucket signed key with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm using Terraform to manage my GCP ressources. In order to have signed URL with expiration I've made a POC with https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#configuring_google_compute_engine_vm_instances
I can put bucket, loadbalancing stuff in Terraform but I can not find any information to configure with terraform this command:

```
gcloud compute backend-buckets \
  add-signed-url-key [BACKEND_NAME] \
  --key-name [KEY_NAME] \
  --key-file [KEY_FILE_NAME]
```

Appreciate any thoughts and help.

EDIT:

Self answer

New resource in terraform [terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/compute_backend_bucket_signed_url_key.html) and [Github source](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/blob/master/google/resource_compute_backend_service_signed_url_key.go)

So bash/CLI/manual action needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't had a change to try this myself yet I thing that what you are looking for in terraform is [google_storage_object_signed_url](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/signed_url.html)

```
data "google_storage_object_signed_url" "get_url" {
  bucket       = "fried_chicken"
  path         = "path/to/file"
  content_md5  = "pRviqwS4c4OTJRTe03FD1w=="
  content_type = "text/plain"
  duration     = "2d"
  credentials  = "${file("path/to/credentials.json")}"

  extension_headers {
    x-goog-if-generation-match = 1
  }
}
```

Comment: This allow to generate a signed URL for a specific resource in a bucket. This is the part "creating signed urls" https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#creating_signed_urls